# SQLAlchemy 0.6.5 (and 0.6.8) SessionExtension after_flush doesn't gets called

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I don't get it, but this code doesn't call after_flush/before_flush/after_flush_postexec

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import SessionExtension

class AfterFlushExtension(SessionExtension):
    def before_commit(self, session):
        print "> before_commit"

    def after_commit(self, session):
        print "> after_commit"

    def before_flush(self, session, flush_context, instances):
        print '> before_flush'

    def after_flush(self, session, flush_context):
        print '> after_flush'

    def after_flush_postexec(self, session, flush_context):
        print '> after_flush_postexec'

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=AfterFlushExtension()))
session.flush()
session.commit()
```

And a result:

```
$ python ~/Dropbox/playground/python/sqlalchemy_hook_test/main.py 
> before_commit
> after_commit
```

Comment: Have you tried this where there is something actually waiting to be flushed? Does flush do anything if there is nothing to do in a flush? Let us know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Bayer answered on SQLAlchemy's mailing list https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/GrMZGtJ-yc8/mCviGB6g9HYJ :

> The flush events only fire off if
>   there's actually something to be
>   flushed.  It would be inefficient for
>   the events to be emitted for every
>   flush() as flush is in fact called a
>   great number of times, on every query,
>   assuming autoflush enabled.  For this
>   reason a flush() with a session that
>   has no change events of any kind
>   quickly checks some flags and returns.
>
> Think of before_flush() really being
>   called
>   before_flush_on_pending_changes() if
>   that helps.
>
> I'll check the docstrings to see if
>   any clarification is needed.

Thanks, Michael